# How do I launch the dart migration tool from sample flutter example?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to run the dart migration tool on the sample application I created from Android Studio (the counter app).  I added one line that should be flagged.  I have the same issue on a larger project so trying to figure it out here on smallest scale.

pubspec.yaml:  sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'

Flutter 3.7.12 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 4d9e56e694 (5 months ago) • 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

When I run `dart migrate`

The output is

> Before migrating your package, we recommend ensuring that every
> library it imports (either directly or indirectly) has been migrated
> to null safety, so that you will be able to run your unit tests in
> sound null checking mode.  You are currently importing the following
> non-null-safe libraries:
>
> package:migrate1/main.dart
>
> Please upgrade the packages containing these libraries to null safe
> versions before continuing.  To see what null safe package versions
> are available, run the following command: `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety`.

I would expect that the migration web tool should load to migrate main.dart, not consider it an imported library. Related? https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45478

```html
name: migrate1
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: What is `package:migrate1`?  Is that the name of the package for your sample application?  What are the contents of your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: migrate1 is just the sample application that flutter creates from the create project menu. pubspec yaml attached

Comment: Have you tried importing `main.dart` via a relative path (e.g. `import 'main.dart';`) instead of via a `package:` path?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about.  main.dart is not imported anywhere I'm aware of.  The project/app has one file main.dart as created boilerplate by android studio.  I thought it only knew about main.dart as convention in /lib

Answer (score 0):

Going line by line - changing these (removing the consts)

```
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
```

to this

```
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

this

```
runApp(const MyApp());
```

to this:

```
  runApp(MyApp());
```

And removing `const MyApp({super.key});`

Let's the migration tool launch

Comment: Still not sure why this makes a difference